# Firebase init app "secondary" not working Android Dev

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

So my situation is this. I'm working on a legacy project that has over 6 different build variants. I've been tasked with addressing why notifications aren't working.

After some logging i see that the sender id is pointing to one of the dev project google-services.json file.

After much trial and error I've decided to go full scorched earth and remove all google-services.json files and use the "secondary" methods.

So with all of those files nuked completely from my code I have the following in Application onCreate method:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setProjectId(newId)
            .setGcmSenderId(newSenderId)
            .setApplicationId(appId)
            .setApiKey(apiKey)
            .build();
    FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, options, "secondary");
        // And logging with this
        Log.d("MYAPP", "FCM APP: " + app.getName());
        String projectID = FirebaseApp.getInstance().getOptions().getProjectId();
        String senderID = FirebaseApp.getInstance().getOptions().getGcmSenderId();
        Log.d("MYAPP", "Project ID: " + projectID);
        Log.d("MYAPP", "Sender ID: + " + senderID);
```

What I'm seeing in the logs is the old sender id and keys. I've went through and removed any instance of those strings from the entire codebase. It makes no sense. I've invalidated caches, wiped my emulators and so on and I'm still getting the old keys back in logging.

Anyone else have this issue before?
My goal is to be able to manually set the firebase project and credentials without any google-services.json files at all. (Which as mentioned have been wiped from the project.)